# Can I use this fn alias in jquery?

Tags: jquery

// plugin background

```
(function ( $ ) {

    // background

    $.fn.background = function( color )

    { $.fn.css({ 'background-color':'#'+color+'' }); };

}( jQuery ));

// usage for black background color for element #div

$('#div').background('000000');
```

Comment: `$.fn.css` will be called with no context, it won't know which element to color.

Answer (score 4):

That would be :

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.background = function(color) {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#' + color);
        });
    };
}(jQuery));

$(function() { // you still need a DOM ready handler

    $('#div').background('000000');

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CgtFB/)

`this` in the plugin references the element

Comment: For chainability, you can `return this.css(...` :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat - I always return the each function, to avoid issues when passing collections etc, but for just setting the CSS, just returning the collection would work.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - and right you where, it's good practice to make plugins chainable. Thanks.